# How to add a new language in Protégé?

Tags: ontology, protege

In Protégé ontology editor, how to add a new language that could be selected when editing a rdfs:label?
I am using version 5.1.0 and didn't find any hint, neither on the web nor in the soft preferences.
Thank you.